Infinite-dimensional normed vector spaces have continuous linear functional.
I'm reading Sheldon Axler's Measure theory book, and in a subsection dedicated to the Hahn-Banach Theorem, he states:

In this subsection, we show that infinite-dimensional normed vector
spaces have plenty of continuous linear functional. We do did by
showing that a bounded linear functional on a subspace of a normed
vector space can be extended to a bounded linear functional on the
whole space without increasing its norm.

I don't understand how the Hahn-Banach theorem can be used to show that every infinite-dimensional normed vector have 'plenty' (how does one define this?) of continuous/bounded linear functionals.

It's easy to define continuous linear functionals on small subspaces, one-dimensional ones for example, and by Hanh-Banach those extend to continuous functionals on the whole space

@AlessandroCodenotti could you give some examples please? Are some of those interesting for, or with applications in, Probability/Statistics?

If you have a finite-dimensional subspace with basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ you can define a linear functional by mapping $v_i$ to $\Bbb R$ arbitrarily and extending by linearity to the whole finite-dimensional subspace. Continuity of this functional is free, because the starting space is finite-dimensional.

One very useful corollary of Hahn - Banach is that, for any point $x$ in your normed space, there exists a bounded functional $f$ such that $f(x) = |x|$. (Define $f_0$ on the linear span of $x$ by $f_0(λx) = λ |x|$ and then extend $f_0$ on the entire space).

"Plenty" in this case is often taken to mean that bounded linear functionals separate points: given any distinct $x,y\in X$, there exists $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$ (or, equivalently, if $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f\in X^*$ then $x=y$).
For this it is enough to show that given $x\in X$ nonzero, there exists $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$ (and then you would apply this statement to $x-y$). Let $X_0=\operatorname{span}\{x\}$. Define $f_0(\lambda x)=\lambda\,\|x\|$. Then
$$
|f_0(\lambda x)|=|\lambda|\,\|x\|=\|\lambda x\|,
$$
so $f_0$ is bounded with $\|f_0\|=1$. By Hahn-Banach there exists $f\in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=\|f_0\|=1$, and $f$ agrees with $f_0$ on $X_0$, so $f(x)=1$.

Martin, thanks for the reply. I still have some doubts, though. Reading the quote from the book, the expression 'plenty' seemed to refer to a 'big' quantity of linear functionals. I don't see how your notion of functionals that separate points relates to this. Instead of $f(x) \neq f(y)$, don't you mean something like $f_x \neq f_y$, where $f_x(x) = 1$?

I meant what I said. The result (and a few consequences of it) imply that the dual is "big enough", in several senses. One is that mentioned in the answer, that bounded linear functionals separate points. A refinement of this is that $$|x|=\max{|f(x)|:\ f\in X^,\ |f|=1}$$for all $x\in X$. You can also use a version of what I wrote in my answer to prove that if $Y\subset X$ is any subspace, given any $x\in X\setminus\overline Y$ there exists $f\in X^$ with $f(x)=1$ and $f|Y=0$. All this assertions point to "the dual has lots of functionals". (continues)

(continued) You can also phrase Hahn-Banach in terms of separation of convex sets, which again tells you that there are lots and lots of functionals in the dual. In set theoretic terms, the cardinality of $X^*$ is at least as big as that of $X$, and can actually be strictly bigger in some cases.

Martin, thanks for the comments. I still can't see how «All these assertions point to "the dual has lots of functionals"». Why is that?

I think I may be missing some basic information, since I'm studying this by myself... Something that you may be assuming as trivial, may not be to me. Regardless, thanks for the patience, so far.

Good for you if you are learning this on your own. I'm afraid I'm not sure what else to tell you. I don't know kind what assertion would satisfy you.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't use chat. Comments are fine.

Let's focus at more intuitive level.
You wrote previously that "Plenty" in this case is often taken to mean that bounded linear functionals separate points. Why would the notion of 'having linear functionals that separate points' be consistent/congruent/agreing with the notion we have at an intuitive level of 'plenty'?
Oh... I think I get it. It means that : « there are ENOUGH/SUFFICIENT bounded linear functionals on a given vector space X to "separate ANY pair of points".»
Is this what you mean? But still, it's seems a 'convoluted' way to define 'plenty'.

Yes, that's it, and it does mean "plenty". You have at least one functional per pair of points. You also have, for each point, a sequence of functionals of norm 1 where they approach the norm. Algebraically, the dimension of the dual is at least as big as the dimension of the space. All those things point to the fact that there are lots and lots of bounded linear functionals at hand: "plenty" .

Thanks, I can now accept this answer, and +1 for the patience. ;)

My pleasure, and I'm still amazed that you are studying this on your own :)
